# Unity Mobile WebGL compatibility

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I ran WebGL version of my project on website, it displays: `please note that unity webgl is not currently supported on mobiles`

When I hit ok, my game still runs like normal, so why it states it does not support mobiles? Can I disable the alert?

Comment: Using a common search engine I found: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1339261/unity-webgl-disable-mobile-warning.html

Comment: thank you, I didnt notice that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It runs on *your* phone and *your* browser, but it's still far from general support, and [it's why Unity is discouraging this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-browsercompatibility.html).

As for disabling the warning, it's implemented at the beginning of `UnityLoader.js` and you can easily remove it.

`var UnityLoader=UnityLoader||{compatibilityCheck:function(e,t,r){UnityLoader.SystemInfo.hasWebGL?UnityLoader.SystemInfo.mobile?e.popup("Please note that Unity WebGL is not currently supported on mobiles. Press OK if you wish to continue anyway.",[{text:"OK",callback:t}]) (...)`

Comment: Thanks for replying, so as far as my mobile app only uses simple features and I successfully test my web application on multiple mobiles, I can safely use it as a to-client web app?

Comment: I wouldn't say "safely". In my experience even simple Unity WebGL games are almost unusable (low fps, very high touch input lag, browser slowdown and crashes), but if you somehow manage to get them to work semi-reliably then it's not like anybody's going to stop you.

Comment: I made this change and it still shows the warning message. I also cleared browser cache to no avail. Any thoughts why this might be happening? @apk

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Build** directory and open **UnityLoader.js** file and
replace this code

```
compatibilityCheck: function(e, t, r) { UnityLoader.SystemInfo.hasWebGL ? UnityLoader.SystemInfo.mobile ? e.popup("Please note that Unity WebGL is not currently supported on mobiles. Press OK if you wish to continue anyway.", [{ text: "OK", callback: t }]) : ["Edge", "Firefox", "Chrome", "Safari"].indexOf(UnityLoader.SystemInfo.browser) == -1 ? e.popup("Please note that your browser is not currently supported for this Unity WebGL content. Press OK if you wish to continue anyway.", [{ text: "OK", callback: t }]) : t() : e.popup("Your browser does not support WebGL", [{ text: "OK", callback: r }]) },
```

to

```
compatibilityCheck: function(e, t, r) { t(); },
```

So, change this **compatibilityCheck** function to remove this warning.[reference](https://naisky.com/2019/05/22/please-note-that-unity-webgl-is-not-currently-supported-on-mobiles-press-ok-if-you-wish-to-continue-anyway-ok/)